# Does noise texture node parameters affect on performance?

Tags: materials, performance

I've connected noise texture node in my material and when I'm changing *scale* parameter, I hear that my graphic card starts work louder. So I suppose it's need more cooling - doing more operations. Am I right with my assumption that *scale* parameter in noise texture is affecting on performance? Of course, I know that other nodes has their effects (especially bump node) too, but I see difference with changing *scale*.
Here's my material:
[image]

Comment: When you're changing settings on nodes, the render viewport is constantly updating and resampling the scene.  The Detail slider does have an effect on how efficient the node is.

Comment: @AllenSimpson so the scale slider does no have an effect on how efficient the node is?

Comment: It may, but I've never heard anything definitive on it.  Probably negligible if anything.

Comment: @AllenSimpson can you give me a hint where I can find more about it? Documentation has no answer to my question(

Comment: I feel like I read a dev post about it at developer.blender.org but I can't remember now

Comment: @AllenSimpson oh, thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally speaking, and just looking at the node alone: No, not really. Only when changing a value, computing power is used. However, it always depends very much on what else you do with these values, so it always depends on your setup.